# extract all suggestions from drop menu selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

how can I get all "suggestions" made by the website to be stored in a list,I tried sending "*" to get all but it didn't work (it only got 4)

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver')
driver.get('https://giveandgetlocal.com/')
input_path = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@placeholder="Enter address or city"]')
input_path.send_keys("n") #new york ....
```

Ideally I want a list with all suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moment the "n" key is send, the site adds some divs with the suggestions. You could take them from there.

But if you want all of them, I think you will have to use Google API, as they use it too, for their suggestions.

When you open the console of your browser and go the "Network" section, you can type something in to see the request pop up. You can find Google-API's documentation on this [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-queryprediction)

Comment: I have a google dev account, is there a way to use my API key to get the results from there as well ? (I tried `curl` but can't seem to find a the way of passing a parameter I choose)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I just found out, that you can download the .js file that Google returns every time you type in a charachter. It's called "AutocompletionService.js". I don't think you can use your own API key to get their results, but you can get the whole list of autocompletions and save it to your project instead. I don't think these locations will change that often, so that could be suitable too.

Comment: I also wanted to prved the link to you, so here you go: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/AutocompletionService.GetPredictionsJson?1sa&4sde-DE&7scountry%3AUS&15e3&20s48EDC768-6A81-42A6-AB53-935393CFA131a2bxauvfccv5&21m1&2e1&callback=_xdc_._49oj90&key=AIzaSyDD8LALkNo36hN295bcI3Wim-LUvlm5G3s&token=1628

Answer (score 0):

To get all the records induce `WebDriverWait`() and `visibility_of_all_elements_located`() and following css selector.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver')
driver.get('https://giveandgetlocal.com/')
input_path = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@class="address-input__input text-input "]')
input_path.send_keys("new york") #new york ....
suggestions=[item.text for item in WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.address-input__suggestion")))]
print(suggestions)
print(len(suggestions))
```

**Output**:

```
  ['New York, NY, USA', 'New York-New York Hotel & Casino, South Las Vegas Boulevard, Las Vegas, NV, USA', 'New York University, New York, NY, USA', 'New York Hilton Midtown, 6th Avenue, New York, NY, USA', 'New York Public Library - Stephen A. Schwarzman Building, 5th Avenue, New York, NY, USA']
5
```

Comment: to collect all I guess I have to loop through all the letters and gather the listings right?

Comment: If you want to search more items like New York then Yes that’s right.